# Сообщение "unable to open include file `Stdio.h`"

Tags: установка, ide, borland

Мне нужно установить на комп Borland C 3.1. В общем, скинул я его распаковавшим, начал работать, при проверке пишет:

> "unable to open include file `Stdio.h`".

И так со всеми библиотеками, можно ли что-то сделать или нет?

Comment: установить по нормальному? ^^

Comment: В с++ borland compiler 5 для Windows 10 все решилось заменой двойных скобок на кавычки ("") в 2 конфигах ! вот только какая то ругань осталась, exe идет

Answer (score 2):

1. Если компилируете из среды разработки, то в меню Options->Directories нужно прописать пути к папкам LIB и INCLUDE
2. Если компилируете из командной строки, то в файле TURBOC.CFG, лежащем в папке BIN нужно прописать путь к папкам INCLUDE и LIB, например (если распаковано в C:\BORLANDC\):

   ```
   -IC:\BORLANDC\INCLUDE
   -LC:\BORLANDC\LIB
   ```

   а в файле TLINK.CFG только путь к папке LIB:

   ```
   -LC:\BORLANDC\LIB
   ```